# How can I do a normal search on a facebook page with vimperator?

Tags: vimperator

On most pages I can hit the `/` key to search (like the default `CTRL + F` in the browser). However it seems that now when on a facebook page, if I hit the `/` key it jumps straight to the facebook search box. Which is not what I want to do at all. I want to search for text on the current page, not use facebook search to go to another one.

Can anyone tell me how to disable this "feature"?